# Flutter: Is it ok to store dependencies in Widget instance variables outside of the build method?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app I'm using `get_it` to retrieve non-widget related dependencies (e.g. an http service).

Most of the Flutter `Widget` examples that I see don't save any variables in the widget class, but rather they retrieve them in the `#build` method. This makes sense for dependencies that rely on the `context`, but **for other dependencies that don't rely on `context` is it ok to save them as instance variables when the constructor is called?**

I'm not very familiar with the Widget lifecycle so I'm not sure if this could lead to memory leaks, etc if widget instances are discarded. I want to save them as variables because it more clearly documents the dependencies.

### Fetching in `#build`

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build() {
    var myService = GetIt.instance.get<MyService>();
  }
}
```

### Storing in instance variable

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyService myService;

  MyWidget(): myService = GetIt.instance.get();

  @override
  Widget build() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why you couldn't store them as an instance variable.

You obviously cannot dispose of instance variables in a manual/clean way and must rely on the garbage collector to do what it should. That could be seen as a drawback. In your case I assume that isn't an issue since the service might live throughout the lifecycle of the app.

If you are very nervous about memory leaks, use a stateful widget and dispose the things needing disposal.

If you very clearly want to document the dependencies you could go further and require it as a parameter to the widget. It would also make the widget more easily testable.